# react native android build shows error "Your request has a malformed header", how to solve it?

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am tring to preduce apk using expo from react native app, however when I make build with android, I am getting this error

```
<Error>
<Code>MalformedSecurityHeader</Code>
<Message>Invalid argument.</Message>
<Details>Your request has a malformed header. Header was included in signedheaders, but not in the request.</Details>
<ParameterName>x-goog-content-length-range</ParameterName>
</Error>
```

what is the issue?
I tried many solutions by adding 'x-goog-content-length-range' and 'x-goog-resumable' to the url headers acrross my app, but nothing seems to work.